Adding a DatePicker into Excel cells using Python XlsxWriter?
I am trying to create an input form using Excel generated by Python XlsxWriter. I wonder is it possible to add a mini calendar (as a DatePicker) into Excel cells for users to input dates?

I stumbled upon this guide provided by Microsoft Support team
Insert a date picker: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-date-picker-afa0aea0-d4e3-4424-8e0a-c08f65928f84


This looks abosolutely cool! But I cannot find anything similar in the XlsxWriter doc unfortunately..
Other variant:

Here is my current code snippet. I am using data_validation to force user to input a date by format in selected cells. I would love to have a way to insert a DatePicker component into the Excel cell.
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

input_table = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["Name", "Desc", "RegisterDate"])

with pd.ExcelWriter("input-form.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    input_table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Input Table", index=False)
    worksheet = writer.sheets["Input Table"]
    worksheet.data_validation(
        'C2:C100',
        {
            "validate": "date",
            "criteria": "between",
            "minimum": date(1, 1, 1),
            "maximum": date(9999, 12, 31),
        },
    )

Does anyone have any experience with generating Excel with a mini calendar?

I think most of these DP controls are not supported in later Windows/Excel releases

Just to confirm that this type of form control isn't supported by XlsxWriter.

very unfortunately, it seems like that's the case... :(
